# How to iterate `dict` with `enumerate` and unpack the index, key, and value along with iteration

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, enumerate

How to iterate a dict with `enumerate` such that I could unpack the index, key and value at the time of iteration?

Something like:

```py
for i, (k, v) in enumerate(mydict):
    # some stuff
```

I want to iterate through the keys and values in a dictionary called `mydict` and count them, so I know when I'm on the last pair.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with indices on a dict?

Comment: I'm printing the dict to a file, so I need to know when to insert a newline.

Comment: Does the index matters for that? At the end of the loop you know that you're done with the dict and can insert a newline.

Comment: I insert a comma between each value (it's a .csv) and I need to know when to insert a comma and when to insert a newline.

Comment: do not re-invent the wheel, use `csv` built-in module, it has `dict`s support

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Instead of using `mydict`, you should be using [`mydict.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) with [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#enumerate) as:

```
for i, (k, v) in enumerate(mydict.items()):
    # your stuff
```

Sample example:

```
mydict = {1: 'a', 2: 'b'}
for i, (k, v) in enumerate(mydict.items()):
    print("index: {}, key: {}, value: {}".format(i, k, v))

# which will print:
# -----------------
# index: 0, key: 1, value: a
# index: 1, key: 2, value: b
```

**Explanation:**

- [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#enumerate) returns an iterator object which contains tuples in the format: `[(index, list_element), ...]`
- [`dict.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) returns an iterator object *(in Python 3.x. It returns `list` in Python 2.7)* in the format: `[(key, value), ...]`
- On combining together, `enumerate(dict.items())` will return an iterator object containing tuples in the format: `[(index, (key, value)), ...]`

Answer (score 1):

It's also possible to use `itertools.count` to count along.

```py
from itertools import count
for i, (k, v) in zip(count(), mydict.items()):
    # do something
```

This is useful especially if you want the counter to be fractional numbers. For example,

```py
mydict = dict(zip(range(3), range(10, 13)))

for i, (k, v) in zip(count(step=0.5), mydict.items()):
    print(f"index={i:<3}, key={k}, value={v}")
    
# index=0  , key=0, value=10
# index=0.5, key=1, value=11
# index=1.0, key=2, value=12
```