# Enumerate Dictionary Iterating Key and Value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, enumerate

I have a dictionary called `regionspointcount` that holds region names (`str`) as the keys and a count of a type of feature within that region (`int`) as the values e.g. `{'Highland':21}`.

I am wanting to iterate the key and value of dictionary while enumerating. Is there a way to do something like:

```
for i, k, v in enumerate(regionspointcount.items()):
```

or do I have to resort to using a count variable?

Comment: Unpack with a tuple -> `for i, (k, v) in enumerate(regionspointcount.items()):`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ As simple as this comment may be, it should be an answer (and not a comment).

Comment: The “index” of a dictionary key doesn’t have any meaning, as they aren’t ordered. What’s the problem you’re really trying to solve? Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42193712/how-to-iterate-dict-with-enumerate-and-unpack-the-index-key-and-value-alon

Comment: The index does matter if the dictionary is [sorted](https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2007/09/how-to-sort-python-dictionary-by-keys/) :)

Comment: ...which yours isn’t, at least as far as the example goes. If the order matters, consider using OrderedDict or another ordered data structure.

Comment: Worm, if you're trying to hold counts, you should look at my favourite data structure: `collections.Counter`.

Comment: Mine is @jonrsharpe and now I am selecting the first and last 30 entries. I left this information out so as not to confuse the question with too much information. Thanks to COLDSPEED I have a solution that I am happy with.

Comment: I will look into collections. Thanks @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ :)

Comment: @Worm Asking questions that are a duplicate is NOT a crime. The duplicates serve as signposts to the original. In some cases, the duplicates receive even better answers than the original, which is a win for everyone.

Comment: Noted @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ. I had the impression that they were a grievous sin. Cheers for your help.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Given a dictionary `d`:

```
d
# {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3, 'D': 4}
```

You can use a tuple to unpack the key-value pairs in the `for` loop header.

```
for i, (k, v) in enumerate(d.items()):
     print(i, k, v)

# 0 A 1
# 1 B 2
# 2 C 3
# 3 D 4
```

To understand why the extra parens are needed, look at the raw output from `enumerate`:

```
list(enumerate(d.items()))
# [(0, ('A', 1)), (1, ('B', 2)), (2, ('C', 3)), (3, ('D', 4))]
```

The key-value pairs are packaged inside tuples, so they must be unpacked in the same way.

Comment: It is useful to also know that `list(enumerate(d.items()))` will be unpacked as  `[(0, ('A', 1)), (1, ('C', 3)), (2, ('B', 2)), (3, ('D', 4))]`. This is the reason behind unpacking them as seperate tuples.

Comment: This is all in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42193712/how-to-iterate-dict-with-enumerate-and-unpack-the-index-key-and-value-alon

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks. Since I've answered, I don't think I should close it. Will you mark it? Also, I think it's fine to leave as a suitable dupe, the wording is different enough that it needn't be downvoted.

Comment: I’d already have done, but I’m out of votes.

Comment: Sorry for the very similar question. I did a decent search of SO and other sites but could't find a duplicate

Answer (score 15):

Assuming you just want to enumerate the key/value pairs (and don't need the index `i`), you can iterate `d.items()` directly:

```
d = {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3, 'D': 4}
for k, v in d.items():
    print(k, v)
```

This prints something like

```
A 1
C 3
B 2
D 4
```

Note that entries are not necessarily ordered.

Comment: OP states explicitly that he wants to enumerate (i.e. have an index number at his disposal) while iterating key-value-pairs. Thus your assumption of not needing the index i is sadly incorrect.

Comment: @MA53QXR Just read the title: iterating key and value. It does _not_ say iterating key, index and value.